# Button click increment only one item and stays at that item even though I click on the button multiple time

Tags: android, android-layout, onclick, uibutton

I implemented a way for my app to navigate to the next item when I click on the `next` button. But for some reason my app will only increment the `position once` and stay at the same item even though I click on the button multiple times in the same screen. Is there anything I'm doing wrong in my loop that is causing this to increment only once?

```
public int index_positionPlus;
public int index_positionMinus;
public String video_URL;
public long currentPosition;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle saveInstanceState) {
    final View rootView  = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rightside_video_fragment, parent, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, rootView);

    currentPosition = C.TIME_UNSET;
    if (saveInstanceState != null) {
        stepDataModels = getArguments().getParcelableArrayList("steps_list");
        mListIndex = saveInstanceState.getInt(ARG_POSITION);
        currentPosition = saveInstanceState.getLong("selected_position", C.TIME_UNSET);
    } else {
            stepDataModels = getArguments().getParcelableArrayList("steps_list");
    }

    if (stepDataModels != null) {
        recipeInstructions.setText(stepDataModels.get(mListIndex).getDescription().toString());
        video_URL = stepDataModels.get(mListIndex).getVideoURL().toString();
    }

    nextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(mListIndex >= 0 && mListIndex <= stepDataModels.size()) {
                index_positionPlus = mListIndex + 1;
                recipeInstructions.setText(stepDataModels.get(index_positionPlus).getDescription().toString());
                video_URL = stepDataModels.get(index_positionPlus).getVideoURL().toString();
            } else {
                recipeInstructions.setText(stepDataModels.get(mListIndex).getDescription().toString());
                video_URL = stepDataModels.get(mListIndex).getVideoURL().toString();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: `index_positionPlus = 0;` init this outside .. **everytime click button its value is 0**

Comment: I made `index_positioPlus` into my global and its still increment only once

Comment: put your latest code please @KHA

Comment: @SantanuSur posted latest code change. What I did was I removed `index_positionPlus = 0;` inside onClick and added that code inside the global variable

Comment: ok so whats your problem now ?? your `index_positionPlus` isnt getting incremented ?

Comment: I was able to solve it. I needed to set `mListIndex` equal to the position `index_positionPlus` was in whenever it was clicked

Comment: yea i was able to say that .. `index_positionPlus = index_positionPlus + 1;` it would be the correct one .. !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make

```
 index_positionPlus = 0;
```

into global.
Everytime the function is called index_positionPlus resets to zero.

Comment: I made `index_positioPlus` into my global and its still increment only once

Comment: there may be a problem in your if condition, try getting the value of the mListIndex everytime you click the button.